# How to Graphically Represent Business Workflow in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, razor, workflow

I have requirement to graphically represent a Workflow (Business Process Flow) in ASP.NET MVC view. I have this entire workflow in a single object. This object is the root of the Workflow sequence that also holds reference to the succeeding workflow sequences in it. The structure of the class is somewhat like this:

```
public class WfSequence{ 

  //Here goes other properties of WfSequence

  public ICollection<WfSequence> NextSequences {get;set;}
}
```

Now in this situation what is the best way represent the workflow graphically. I am looking for something like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/diagram/index.html. But unfortunately using Kendo UI is not an option.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: If this is just a view that does not need dynamic data interaction, why not just build the HTML to make it look like what you want? Or just create a picture in photoshop or some other tool to look like your workflow, then insert that picture into the view?

Comment: The problem here is that the application is multi-tenant and for each tenant the workflow sequence is different. Hence to create HTML for each of the workflow is not an option. Same applies for photoshop images. Doing so will create a maintenance overhead. Hence for these reason the representation logic needs to support dynamic business workflow.